# Use Picasso to get a callback with a Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I'm using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to download images for my app.

I'm in a situation where I need to access the `Bitmap` first before it's loaded into the `ImageView`. The presence of the `Downloader.Response` class seems to suggest this is possible, but I can't find any use examples. I don't want to write a bunch more code to asynchronously handle this one particular case if it's possible to do with Picasso.

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36310327/5028508

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Found the answer on github in case anyone is wondering:

```
private Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      }
}

private void someMethod() {
   Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
}

@Override 
public void onDestroy() {  // could be in onPause or onStop
   Picasso.with(this).cancelRequest(target);
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

The post recommends not using an anonymous callback, and instead using an instance variable for target.

Comment: Ideally you'd implement `Target` on a view or view holder object directly. If you aren't doing this, you need to maintain a strong reference to the instance somewhere otherwise it will get garbage collected.

Comment: @JakeWharton: if I want to apply a custom animation on every item of a  `ListView`, you suggest to do something like:
`private static ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Target target = new Target() {
        public void onBitmapLoaded() { // do animation on imageView }
    }
}`?

Comment: @JakeWharton explains it here https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/308 in the last comment.

Comment: onBitmapLoaded not call at first time after onPrepareLoad

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm only missing a super call in onDestroy.

Comment: using a Target bypasses the nice alpha animation done by the `PicassoDrawable`. I'd like to keep that behaviour and get the bitmap at the same time to add an overlay with a color generated from the `Palette` api. Any way to do that ?

Comment: I want to use Target in Kotlin but it's giving error ..."This type is final, so it can not be inherited from"

Comment: How to do this on the main thread? If we use another thread, it takes some time. and the purpose of the process gets wasted. There is a continuous process after loading into a bitmap. anyone can help on this?

Comment: Image not load first time. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 74):

taken from [here](http://pr8x.com/st/questions/24682217/get-bitmap-from-imageview-loaded-with-picasso.html):

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
            /* Save the bitmap or do something with it here */

            //Set it in the ImageView
            theView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
        }
});
```

Updated (May 04, 2016):

```
            Picasso.with(this)
                .load(youUrl)
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });
```

Updated (November 22, 2016)

or using a strong reference for `Target` so that it wont be garbage collected

```
Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };


void foo() {
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(getUrl()).into(target);
}
```

Kotlin

```
object: com.squareup.picasso.Target {
                  override fun onBitmapFailed(e: java.lang.Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }

                  override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
                    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                  }

                  override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {

                  }
                }
```

Comment: anonymous Target could be garbage collected

Comment: @SteveM And what would that do? Cancel the request? Prevent bitmap from being loaded?

Comment: @nurettin I'm assuming Picasso (or Glide) has some sort of weak reference to the target. So if it's anonymous there is no hard reference and it's vulnerable to GC. When Picasso checks the reference it will be null so the callback won't be called.

Comment: So this solution is really bad because the GC may occasionally run in between the loading and calling of the callback and cause callback to not be called.

Comment: @SteveM I host an application on google play that loads a bunch of icons during the scroll of its listviews with at least 2000 users at any instance, scaling some of the icons using this method, but I haven't seen any complaint, comment (I get lots) or crash report about icons not loading. So at least anecdotally, it isn't getting garbage collected for some reason.

Comment: @nurettin I guess you are lucky. The author of Picasso (Jack Wharton) specifically warns against it as a comment to the accepted answer. It is also warned against in the Glide documentation which is a very similar library. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-callbacks-simpletarget-and-viewtarget-for-custom-view-classes under "Pay Attention with Targets".

Comment: @SteveM Thanks for making the point, I updated the application just in case.

Comment: For the Kotlin, it needs to be 'onBitmapFailed(e: Exception, errorDrawable: Drawable?)'

Answer (score 11):

What can be easy than next:

```
val url: String = "https://...."
val bitmap: Bitmap = Picasso.with(context).load(url).get()
```

**Should be called from not the main thread!**

or with RxJava 2:

```
fun getBitmapSingle(picasso: Picasso, url: String): Single<Bitmap> = Single.create {
    try {
        if (!it.isDisposed) {
            val bitmap: Bitmap = picasso.load(url).get()
            it.onSuccess(bitmap)
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        it.onError(e)
    }
}
```

Retrieve Bitmap:

```
getBitmapSingle(Picasso.with(context), "https:/...")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ bitmap ->
                // val drawable = BitmapDrawable(context, bitmap)
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
```

I used Picasso v.2.5.2

Answer (score 2):

I thought maybe some of you would like an RxJava version of the above answer... Here it is:

```
    public static Observable<Bitmap> loadBitmap(Picasso picasso, String imageUrl) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Bitmap> subscriber) {
            Target target = new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    subscriber.onNext(bitmap);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    subscriber.onError(new Exception("failed to load " + imageUrl));
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                }
            };
            subscriber.add(new Subscription() {
                private boolean unSubscribed;

                @Override
                public void unsubscribe() {
                    picasso.cancelRequest(target);
                    unSubscribed = true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isUnsubscribed() {
                    return unSubscribed;
                }
            });
            picasso.load(imageUrl).into(target);
        }
    });
}
```

P.S. When subscribing, store the subscription reference on your activity, otherwise, target will be GC'd before you receive a response...

Comment: Seems this code is not working now with latest RxAndroid