# Store image key hashmap (persistent data) in internal/external storage

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader, picasso

I am building a multilevel navigation drawer in my application where I would need to cache some 70-80 images which I do not want to download in front of users. Right now, I am using picasso image library which allows me to load images once the app gets started.
Load:

```
Picasso.with(getActionBar().getThemedContext()).load(imageURL);
Setting image in view:
Picasso.with(_context).load(imageURL).into(ImageView);
```

I want to store the images in user's phone so that the drawer could show them up even when the user is offline. I am not sure if I should use internal or external storage(also how would I use). Is there a way I could store these images in phone using picasso somehow because the effects picasso has for image loading seems good.

If not, how should I go about storing my images? I cannot hardcode this because these images would change every 2-4 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the images like this:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f = new File (sdcard, "filename.png");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out)
```

Comment: Is there way I could get the bitmap through picasso?

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181491/use-picasso-to-get-a-callback-with-a-bitmap