# Animated loading image in picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have the following code to load an image in Picasso, using a drawable for the placeholder to display while the image is downloading. What I want though is an animated spinning progress bar style spinner that animates around and around while the image is loading, like I see in most professional apps. Picasso doesn't seem to support this, only static image drawables. Is there a way to get it working with Picasso or do I have to do something different?

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url)             
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .error(R.drawable.image_download_error)
                    .into(view);
```

Answer (score 270):

How to have a loading progress animation image using Picasso placeholder:

I solved this easily using a animated-rotate xml object.

Steps:

**progress_image.png**

[image: progress_image.png]

**/res/drawable/progress_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:gravity="center">
    <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_image"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Picasso loading:**

```
Picasso.with( context )
        .load( your_path )
        .error( R.drawable.ic_error )
        .placeholder( R.drawable.progress_animation )
        .into( image_view );
```

Comment: Yes! I use this for a long time, and now, looking for a oficial documentation about animated-rotate drawables, a didn't find anything.
Did you tested this solution? It's has always worked for me.

Comment: No I haven't tested it yet, because it looked suspicious for me, but if it works it will be cool solution.

Comment: It's not working. Image stays still. I also used my [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27832916/3531756) for rotation but still nothing.

Comment: @DBragion it works great but for large images, it scalled up. can we fix width and height of it to a number like 32x32 pixels?

Comment: Not working. @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush how did you make it work? Any special version of Android?

Comment: Simple solution but I will try to find better solution. User wont be happy seeing loading indicator that is huge.

Comment: This doesn't work, no animation shown. Just a plain image

Comment: doesn't animate just a static image

Comment: Working. Image rotating. Only problem was image bit big. I used photoshop to scale it down. Is there any other android way to scale it down?

Comment: I am afraid you didn't specify height and width , that shows an error in android studio

Comment: you can use this https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html to scale the icon.

Comment: Works fairly well for me.

Comment: @Vlado did you find a solution?

Comment: It is working but I want small loader not as my imageview size loader

Comment: Worked fine, the animation stays small until few milliseconds before the downloaded image appear, it gets maximized and stretched for few milliseconds then the image appear. Is there any solution?

Comment: Use http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html (select "Launcher icon generator") to create mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc.

Comment: Please be sure to use always the latest version of Picasso or the animation won't work as it should be. The min version goes from: compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' to newer versions.

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird Na, it doesn't work with latest one either.

Comment: My experience with this solution caused Picasso `RequestCreator.getPlaceholderDrawable()` to crash on Android versions of Marshmallow (6.xx). Not sure why but it doesn't seem to like the `animated-rotate` inside a `drawable` as a placeholder.

Comment: Works great with Glide too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 77):

I implemented the progress dialog till the image download and its very simple. Take your ImageView in relative layout and place progress loader on same image view. Apply the below code and handle progress dialog visibility only.

```
holder.loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         final ProgressBar progressView = holder.loader;
            Picasso.with(context)
            .load(image_url)
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation(15, 0))
            .fit()
            .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
```

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Actually you should pay attention to weak references and declare a **Callback object** in this way **in order to avoid garbage collection** (otherwise onSuccess could never get called): `final Callback loadedCallback = new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() { // your code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() { // your code
                }
            };
            imageView.setTag(loadedCallback);

            Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView, loadedCallback);`

Comment: Anyone confused by the lingo, a Progress Loader is a Progress Bad

Comment: You missed to add RoundedTransformation class. This class is here
https://gist.github.com/aprock/6213395

Comment: Not helpful if there are multiple images. Makes the UI complex for no reason.

Answer (score 5):

Picasso doesn't support animated placeholders unfortunately.

One way you could work around this is to place your ImageView in a FrameLayout with the animated drawable underneath. This way when Picasso loads the image it will load over the top of the animated placeholder, giving the user the intended effect.

Alternatively, you could load the image into a [Target](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html). Then you'd have the progress bar showing by default, and when the onBitmapLoaded method is called you can hide it and display the image. You can see a basic implementation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181629/1319750)

Comment: Picasso *does* support animated placeholders. You write up the animation drawable file (includes animation list with several items representing each image in the animation). You feed that file to a new AnimationDrawable object and then pass it to placeHolder() in the Picasso loader constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried many ways on the stack overflow and finally found a way to do it is using "**CircularProgressDrawable**". Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/CircularProgressDrawable

Kotlin code sample

```
fun Context.loadImage(view: ImageView, url: String) {
  val circularProgressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(this)
  circularProgressDrawable.apply {
    strokeWidth = 5f
    centerRadius = 30f
    setColorSchemeColors(
      getColor(Color.WHITE)
    )
    start()
  }

  Picasso
    .get()
    .load(url)
    .fit()
    .centerInside()
    .placeholder(circularProgressDrawable)
    .into(view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add shape attribute in DBragion's answer as like below and it will work like charm.
Happy coding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>

        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp"/>

            <solid
                android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="center">
        <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:drawable="@drawable/spinner"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can use Glide too:

```
Glide.with(activity).load(url)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.centerInsideTransform())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                    .into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to this question!

See: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/427#issuecomment-266276253

In addition to answer of @DBragion, try below.

Now we can fix height and width!

```
image_view.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
```

```
picasso.load(your_path)
        .fit()
        .centerCrop()
        .noFade()
        .placeholder(R.drawable. progress_animation)
        .into(image_view)
```

I think there are two key points.

1. use noFade()
2. set image_view's scaleType to "CENTER_INSIDE"

Answer (score 1):

```
   // create a ProgressDrawable object which we will show as placeholder
    CircularProgressDrawable progress = new CircularProgressDrawable(context);
    progress.setColorSchemeColors(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.colorAccent);
    progress.setCenterRadius(30f);
    progress.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    progress.start();

Picasso.with(context).load((String) chatMessage.getPath()).error(R.drawable.error)
                    .placeholder(progress)
                    .noFade()
                    .into(viewHolder.imageBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it working in following way:

1. Created a drawable (found somewhere on the Internet) and put it in the res/drawable:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromDegrees="90"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:toDegrees="360">

   <shape
       android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
       android:shape="ring"
       android:thicknessRatio="7.0">

       <gradient
           android:angle="0"
           android:centerColor="#007DD6"
           android:endColor="#007DD6"
           android:startColor="#007DD6"
           android:type="sweep"
           android:useLevel="false" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. In my item for the GridView added ProgressBar element:

   ```
   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/movie_item_spinner"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/poster_width"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/poster_height"
       android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"/>
   ```
3. In Adapter added Target Object with following parameters, where poster and spinner are references to ImageView and ProgressBar:

   // Target to show/hide ProgressBar on ImageView

   ```
   final Target target = new Target() {

           @Override
           public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {
               poster.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
               spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }

           @Override
           public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap photo, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
               poster.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(photo));
               spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }

           @Override
           public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
               poster.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
           }
       };
   ```
4. Results will be like that on loading - circle is rotating (sorry for this screenshot, but images are appearing too fast):
   [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrdGM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to use DBragion's technique: Make sure you have the latest version of Picasso or else it wont spin. Mine didn't work until I used version 2.5.2.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: This should be a comment under said answer

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1058), Jake Wharton said :

> Nope. We use the Android BitmapFactory for all image decoding and it has no animated GIF support (sadly).

Then you can't

Answer (score 0):

Just use Picasso PlaceHolder

```
  Picasso.get()
        .load(datas[position].artist?.image)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.music_image)
        .error(R.drawable.music_image)
        .into(holder.cardViewImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

@DBragion's answer was great. The problem with it (like many mentioned in the comments) was it didn't provide a way to specify the height / width of the progress indicator. Following is the modified version of his answer with combination of @AkankshaRathod's answer.

**loading_indicator.png** 
[image: Loading Indicator Image]

**progress_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:gravity="center">
        <animated-rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/loading_indicator"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**CardView (or any container Layout) containing your ImageView**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/vCategoryItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_category_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/smaller"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/small">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCategoryImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/demo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loadingIndicator"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/progress_animation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCategoryName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/big"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/big"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/big"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Category Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Picasso loading:**

```
Picasso.get().load(yourImageURL).into(imgCategoryImage, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {

    }
});
```