# ANDROID Progress Dialog when Loading Image on Dialog/Popup

Tags: java, android

I have this working function that load image from url. The only thing is that it shows no progress while loading the image just the screen become dimmer and after some time only the picture is shown. This makes the user think like it is not working. So how do I add progress dialog while the image is loading or any way that shows the image is loading?

```
public void showImage() {
    Dialog builder = new Dialog(this);
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            //nothing;
        }
    });

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://camranger.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Android-Icon.png").into(imageView);
    builder.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated loading image in picasso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826459/animated-loading-image-in-picasso)

Comment: the `.into()` method has the second argument as the callback to check if the image is loaded. Have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void showImage() {
    Dialog builder = new Dialog(this);
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            //nothing;
        }
    });

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("http://camranger.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Android-Icon.png")
            .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                    // The image has loaded you can make the progress bar invisible
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    // Show some error message
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


    builder.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    builder.show();

    progressDialog.setMessage("please wait");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I need to declare the `progressDialog` as `final` but then the `setVisibility` cannot be resolved.

Comment: Now it says method does not override method from its superclass.

Comment: where is that error coming ?? i mean on which specific line?

Comment: Try my edit.. just write `com.squareup.picasso.Callback()` instead of `Callback()`. You may imported wrong package for CallBack. or tell me which package is shown as import for CallBack ??

Comment: ok now its gone but another error shows up. `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: changed the `getApplicationContext()` into `myActivity.this` and finally works :). `this` also works.

Comment: Great.. Happy coding..!! :)

Answer (score 4):

try adding PlaceHolder
add this to layout folder

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/hoteldetails_myContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/hoteldetails_progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hoteldetails_imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this to loading code

```
Picasso.with(this)
        .load(hoteImageStr)
        .error(R.drawable.loading)
        .into(img,  new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (progress != null) {
                    progress .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
```