# show progress bar while loading images in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, picasso

how to show progress bar while loading images. I have tried the code given below

```
 Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(stage1ImageURL)
                    .placeholder(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
                    .error(R.drawable.no_image).into(stage1ImageView);
```

Comment: Refer this link for complete code http://stackoverflow.com/a/25226999/3843374

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official [docs](http://developer.android.com/index.html) how to deal with a progress bar.

In your case, you have to write an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which starts the dialog in onPreExecute() and ends in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses `AsyncTask`:

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    //declare other objects as per your need
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        //show loading dialog
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Process Description Text", true);

        //do initialization of required objects objects here                
    };      
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {   

         //do loading operation here  
        return null;
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    };
}
```

You can call this using from your `onCreate()`:

```
LoadData task = new LoadData();
task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

`progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

to show progressBar. And to hide it,

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25226999/3843374) for complete code.