# show progressbar while loadig images in each image view in Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

how to show progressbar while loading image in each imageview. I have tried the code given below

```
     if (stage1ImageURL.startsWith("http://")) {

                //Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(stage1ImageURL).into(stage1ImageView);
                //imageLoader.DisplayImage((stage1ImageURL), stage1ImageView);
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(stage1ImageURL)
                .into(stage1ImageView , new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: show complete defination of progressBar

Comment: Make use of FrameLayout.

Comment: Refer this link for complete code http://stackoverflow.com/a/25226999/3843374

Answer (score 2):

You can overlap the two views by wrapping with `Framelayout`. Just wrap your progress bar and `ImageView` like below. Then switch `View.VISIBLE`and `View.GONE` on `onSuccess()`

```
<Framelayout
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stage1ImageView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</Framelayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should have something like this

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="50dp"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:progress="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    </ImageView>

   </FrameLayout>
```

And your code in java file looks good. First get the reference of ProgessBar with `findViewById`

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

Then make use of `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)`