# get bitmap image using picasso library

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I want to load large bitmaps efficiently, so i decided to use picasso library.

I have a SurfaceView that must need bitmap to draw something(on surface)

here is my frame-code.

```
Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

if (canvas != null) canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);

// here i want to add some bitmaps

surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

is it possible? get bitmap using picasso library.
i already check usage http://square.github.io/picasso/

but there are not way to get bitmap source using picasso library.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: bitmap source as in?

Comment: Possible solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20181629/5059946)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own class implementing the [Target](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html) interface and then call:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(target);
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be called from not the main thread!

```
val url: String = "https://...."
val bitmap: Bitmap = Picasso.with(context).load(url).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using the following after Picasso loads your image:

```
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)yourImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```