# Bitmap not loading in Imageview

Tags: android, bitmap

I am loading bitmap from a twitter feed. I am using below code

```
private class getBitmapFromLink extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imgView;

    public getBitmapFromLink(ImageView imgView) {
        this.imgView = imgView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap myBitmap;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("BITMAP", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("BITMAP", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imgView.setImageBitmap(result);
        imgView.invalidate();
    }

}
```

When I debug `myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);` line it directly come to catch block and on return null line. While debugging I tried printing error message on logs but it does not execute that line and directly come to return statement.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is the url valid? Why don't you use Picasso or Fresco to deal with pictures ?

Comment: yes. url is valid - http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CWgUjyHUAAA7eZ3.jpg

Comment: use picasso to load image from url, you can check examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181491/use-picasso-to-get-a-callback-with-a-bitmap

Comment: post the stacktrance of the exception, using `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: That log line is not executing. It directly come to return statement in catch block

Comment: put  e.printStackTrace(); in both catch blocks

Comment: @unflagged.destination ....Is my solution workable for you or not??Please let me know if there any concern

Comment: @unflagged.destination ... Did u resolve your problem??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Universal Image Loader** and than

```
  imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ProfileScreen.this));
    imageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.user_icon)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.user_icon)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.user_icon)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .build();
```

And than where you get the url use these lines of code

```
     iimageLoader.displayImage("your url", imgView, imageOptions);

                            imageLoader.loadImage("your url", new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                    // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
                                    imgView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);

                                }
                            });
```

You can also use the **Picasso** library to perform yours operation... for that you can use these lines of code for it

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load("your url").into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    //do what ever you want with your bitmap 
                  imgView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: @unflagged.destination ...Is these solution helpful for you...plz do up-vote or accept if it is helpful for you