# Overlay images with Picasso

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso, android-image

I have one main product image, which always is displayed in my `ImageView`. Now it is possible that there are several overlays (which have the same size as the original image, but a lot of transparent areas).

All those images come from remote URLs. E.g.:

[Main image](http://picscdn.redblue.de/doi/pixelboxx-mss-70013531/mobile_220_310_png/SAMSUNG-Galaxy-S7-edge-32-GB-Schwarz-)

[Overlay](http://picscdn.redblue.de/doi/msh-pixelboxx-2107965959/mobile_220_310_png)

Is it possible to load all of them into one `ImageView`?

Comment: Yes..you can do that  using FrameLayout

Comment: Using multiple ImageViews though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your custom `ImageView`, [load bitmaps with Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181629/1083957) and then draw those bitmaps on canvas:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, null); // lower image
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, null); // upper image
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagef"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ph_bg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I was asking about one ImageView