# null drawable from Picasso ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

Basically, I am trying to convert a URI -> ImageView (via Picasso) -> Drawable.

```
var tempimg = ImageView(this)
var a: String
var d: Drawable

    a = pageURIFd + page
    Picasso.get().load(a).into(tempimg)
    d = tempimg.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable
    bitmaps.add(d)
```

I know the ImageView is not empty after Picasso loads it because I can display the image. But the line below is returning null. I'm trying to add each drawable to an arraylist.

```
d = tempimg.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable
```

Comment: tempimg= findViewById(R.id.ImageView) initilization is missing

Comment: Alternatively, Get bitmap from `Picasso` and convert into `BitmapDrawable`.

Comment: `tempimg.getDrawable()` is not null but `tempimg.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable` is null?

Comment: why do you use ImageView at all, if you don't need it, and want only a Bitmap?

Comment: Sorry, new to android and kotlin. They're both null. I think Wizard has the best suggestion so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `Picasso.get().load(a).into(tempimg)` is *asynchronous*. `Picasso` will do the request in a thread and when it get the result, set it to the `ImageView`. The next lines of code can't get the result of Picasso.

If you would like to get a `Bitmap`, you can ask `Picasso` to return it. See [Use Picasso to get a callback with a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181491/use-picasso-to-get-a-callback-with-a-bitmap)