# Set LocationComponentOptions foregroundDrawable dynamically

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using MapBox `8.4.0` and I have the following snippet to load the map on a fragment, pinning the user's current location with a marker. I need to customize the marker by dynamically setting `foregroundDrawable` with an image loaded from a network URL. But `foregroundDrawable` only accepts a resource ID as parameter.

```
val customOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(context!!)
    .elevation(5f)
    .foregroundDrawable(R.drawable.icon_profile) // set image dynamically
    .backgroundDrawable(R.drawable.icon_current_location)
    .build()

val activationOptions = LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(context!!, style)
    .locationComponentOptions(customOptions)
    .build()

mapboxMap.locationComponent.apply {
    activateLocationComponent(activationOptions)
    isLocationComponentEnabled = true
    cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING
    renderMode = RenderMode.NORMAL
}
```

It should look like this with the `profile icon` replaced with the loaded image at run time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoXuG.jpg

Any way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `foregroundName()` to set dynamic icon for our marker.

```
mapboxMap.getStyle { loadedStyle ->

    loadedStyle.addImage("marker-icon", bitmapIcon) // create a Bitmap icon; you may use Glide to load image from URL

    val locationComponentOptions: LocationComponentOptions =
        LocationComponentOptions.builder(context!!)
            .foregroundName("marker-icon") // set icon for the marker
            .build()

    val activationOptions =
        LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(context!!, loadedStyle)
            .locationComponentOptions(locationComponentOptions)
            .build()

    mapboxMap.locationComponent.apply {
        activateLocationComponent(activationOptions)
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fly by comment here to say that if you're using Picasso instead of Glide, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181629/6358488 shows how to use Picasso to set a target to get the `Bitmap` from the network URL call.